# Installing Firebase tools: Stuck at downloading Chromium

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-hosting

I am trying to run in the terminal of the vs code since I plan to host this online already:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

But it is stuck here:
[image]

This is my package.json

[image]

The version of node.js installed in my computer is:
v14.15.4

Comment: As you didn't get any error but got stcuked, stop that and re-run the command 'npm install -g firebase-tools' or update the node and npm versions and try.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the command with `--loglevel verbose`

This will show the [log information](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/logging), may point to the issue.

The [install](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#windows-npm) generally is pretty smooth, without any problems.